# Matching optional groups

Tags: java, regex

With the following code:

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((foo) (bar)?)|((foo) (baz)?)");

    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("foo baz");

    if(matcher.find()){
        for(int i=1; i<=matcher.groupCount(); i++){
            System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
        }
    }
```

The result is:

```
foo 
foo
null
null
null
null
```

Whereas I was hoping for:

```
null
null
null
foo baz
foo
baz
```

How to match the second item?

I want to match the full "foo baz" if possible, else match "foo"

Comment: Perhaps, you just want [`a(?: [0-9])?`](https://regex101.com/r/sN4aL4/1)? (or with word boundaries `\\ba(?: [0-9])?\\b`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is behaving as expected: Your input `"foo baz"` matches `((foo) (bar)?)`—at least, the `"foo "` part does. In general, regular expressions prefer the *longest* pattern (greedy) defined *first* (left to right), and `"foo "` matches that better than `"foo baz"`.

If you want to ensure that the entire expression is matched, you'll need `^` and `$`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^((foo) (bar)?)$|^((foo) (baz)?)$");
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem is very similar to `a|aa` where `aa` will never get a chance to match anything because left site `a`

- will be executed first
- and will be able to match all singe `a` (even the one in `"aa"`)

You can't change that mechanism of regex and enforce trying to match all `regex1|regex2|regex3` cases because

- it would reduce its performance,
- and probably more important, what if two cases like `regex1` `regex2` would match? For instance if regex will be `a|aa` and we have data like `aaaa`, from where we should start searching next match, from `a:aaa` or `aa:aa` (`:` represents regex cursor)?

So you could rewrite your regex in a way to make sure that it will be able to match fully each case and place more precise match before more general ones like

```
(foo bar)|(foo baz)|(foo)
```

You could also rewrite it as

```
(foo) (?:(bar)|(baz))?
```

Comment: It is hard to help you more without knowing what you really want to achieve.